# How do I remove cross-browser history data on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I just found that Chrome can also sync my historical data.

I visited some URLs on my company's computer. And when I get home, I log on the same Google account, I found that a URL is automatically showed up when I type the first few characters.

How can I remove the data?

Answer (score -1):

chrome://history displays all your history. From there you can delete items. You can search in the search box to restrict the list to some set of items (such as URLs you accessed from work), check off the set of them (on the left), and hit delete (top right).

You can search by date by typing YYYY-MM-DD into the search box (like "2019-12-31" for Dec 31, 2019.

I made two different Chrome profiles so that at work I am logged into Chrome as a different user from my personal account; this way I keep home and work separate, but both are synced and available.